# Custom label for strapi collection when creating an entry

Tags: strapi

So I'm pretty new to Strapi, and I have the following relationship :

[image]

As it can be seen a `country` has many `states`, and each `state` has a `state_info`, however, name in `state` is not unique, so when adding the relationship in Strapi, I can see several states repeated, what I would like to have is Strapi showing something like : `USA - Texas, ..., Germany - Bavaria` etc, is there a way to accomplish this in Strapi?